# How to install WSO2 for PHP

Tags: php, wso2

I'm trying to install ws02/wsf for PHP. In the installation guide it says that:

```
Go to the directory where you have extracted the source distribution. Run the following:

./configure
make
make install
```

But when I go to php folder I can't find the configure file. Can you give me details about installation?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you need to run one of the .sh scripts, try with ./build.sh

Answer (score 0):

Download autoconf

```
 sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

run autoconf on php folder. then try ./configure

Comment: If I run autoconf /home/andrei/Projects/wsf/php/ I get this error: /usr/bin/m4: cannot open `/home/andrei/Projects/wsf/php': Is a directory
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1

Comment: are u using ubuntu or fedora

Comment: are you using github repo or some other svn? whats your release version?